# After Ubuntu install, computer boots directly to windows7, no dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a laptop, where Windows 7 is pre-installed. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with a USB-stick, using this guide https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop with windows7 alongside.

After the installation, it restarts, but it boots directly to windows7, no dual-boot.

Using the USB-stick again, I chose Try Ubuntu and I tried to use Boot-Repair. The recommend fix didnt work. This message shows up

> The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and
>   use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature.
>   For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit
>   (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is
>   set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

Here is the from Boot-Repair generated pastebin http://paste2.org/zKgGF2s5

I dont know what to do next. Can someone please help me_

Comment: As Boot-Repair says, you installed in Legacy/BIOS mode on an UEFI system. You can dual boot, but only from UEFI menu. And may have to turn on/off UEFI and BIOS/CSM/Legacy to have each system work in mode installed. Boot-Repair can convert your install to UEFI boot, if you boot installer in UEFI mode and then run Boot-Repair's advanced mode to uninstall/reinstall correct version of grub.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Most Windows 7 installs are BIOS, but like yours a few are UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of oldfred, I went to help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  and tried to follow the instructions.

First, I disabled quick boot.

Second, there was an option to choose, whether what should start first, UEFI or Legacy. I chose Uefi. Then, I started with the USB-stick again and used Boot-Repair. After that, it seems to work. Thanks to oldfred.